# Python django как сделать админку для статического контента?

Tags: python, django, фреймворк

У меня есть страница в django, вынес её даже в приложение, на ней есть блоки и тому подобное. Вот пример:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне надо чтобы весь этот текст можно было редактировать через админку технически не подкованным пользователем. И потом выводить это на страницу для всех. Задача простая, но решаю её уже день. Создал модель, но не понимаю как вывести на страницу, юзаю цикл и блоки из-за этого дублируются. На PHP делал это за полчаса, по такому алгоритму:

В таблице со столбцами: Контент, название

И на страницу вставлял содержимое по названию из массива, который загружал ajax.

Как мне реализовать такое на django? Как я понимаю здесь модели и не нужны?

Мой код сейчас

models.py

```js
from django.db import models


class Content_index(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('Название (не удалять)', max_length=32)
    content = models.TextField('Содержимое блока')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Содержимое'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Содержимое'
```

admin.py:

```js
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Content_index


admin.site.register(Content_index)
```

views.py:

```js
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Content_index

def index(request):
    content_index = Content_index.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'main/index.html', {'content': content_index})
```

P.S в идеале иметь возможность менять изображения через админку тоже

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В данном случае content_index - это даже не совсем список, а именно, что QuerySet. Тем не менее, по нему можно итерироваться так же, как и по списку:

```html
{% if content %}
        {% for post in content %}
                <div>
                    <h1>{{post.name}}</h1>
                    <p>{{post.content}}</p>
                    <hr>
                </div>
        {% endfor %}
    {% else %}
        <h2>Опубликованных статей нет!</h2>
{% endif %}
```

UPD:
Если я правильно понял обновлённый вопрос, то нужно разные блоки выводить в разные места на странице. В таком случае нужно передавать конкретные блоки отдельно в отображении:

```py
def index(request):
    content_index = Content_index.objects.all()
    blocks = []
    for e in list(Content_index.objects.all().values("name")):
        blocks.append(e["name"])
    content = []
    for e in list(Content_index.objects.all().values("content")):
        content.append(e["content"])
    bc = {b: c for b, c in zip(blocks, content)}
    return render(request, 'main/index.html', bc)
```

Далее просто указываете названия блоков в местах на странице, пример: `{{ myname }}`, где их нужно вывести. А для администрирования, как я уже сказал, можно использовать встроенную админку Django, либо написать форму с использованием jQuery.

Comment: Да, знаю про это применение, но мне надо сделать по другому. Мне надо именно выводить content определенного элемента по его `name`

Comment: Я просто хочу сделать админку на сайт, чтобы можно было через админку менять текста и заголовки на сайте, видимо не правильно реализовал, django учу один день

Comment: Что значит выводить content по его name? Если есть поле, в которое вводится name, а ниже после ввода должен появится content, то нужно это значения перехватывать, и уже на стороне сервера выцеплять нужное значение, например при помощи jQuery, либо через редирект можно сделать штатными средствами Django, но это будет менее удобно. Плюс, можно не изобретать велосипед, если только это действительно не требуется (а если Django учите один день, то требуется очень вряд ли), и воспользоваться встроенной админкой Django

Comment: видимо я не правильно объяснил, вообще это до ужаса простая задача на php такое пишется за минуты, не могу понять как это делать на django.

Comment: я изменил вопрос, посмотрите ещё раз пожалуйста)

Comment: Дополнил ответ.